# Changes to LiveData of composite objects

Tags: android, android-livedata

I want to make sure I understand correctly when is the `onChanged` method of a `LiveData`'s `Observer` called.

Let's say we have an `object A` which has some primitives types
(some ints, some strings, etc.) and an `object B` as fields.

I know that `onChanged` is called when I call `setValue`. I'm pretty sure that it is also called when `A`'s primitive fields change, or when I reassign the object field to a new instance, and that it is NOT called when I change any of `B`'s fields.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Do these rules also apply to a `LiveData` object fetched from Room?
Are there any other cases where `onChanged` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that the `onChanged` method of the `LiveData`'s `Observer` is only called when the containing value of the `LiveData` is being set using `setValue()` or `postValue()` method. There is no mechanism to observe fields inside an object that is held by a `LiveData`. As a result, by changing the value of fields inside `object-A`, the observer shouldn't be notified.

On the other hand, as you know, the methods that are provided by Room to query on a db are able to return `LiveData<SomeType>` instead of `SomeType`. Under the hood, Room creates and registers a [`ContentObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver) on your query's table(s) to get aware of changes in it. So, every time a change occurs on the data, Room gets notified using the mentioned `ContentObserver`, then fetches the query result again and post it on the `LiveData`.